# c# generic method with string and int return

Tags: c#, string, generics, return

I implemented a code that read the value of a variable in a PLC. the value could be of whatever type (bool, string, int16, int32 and so on).
Actually I implemented this code using cast.
But now I saw that cast makes box/unboxing and that's a bad idea for a clean memory usage.
So I'm trying to make the same behavior but with a generic method type which is linked at run  time.
So here is my code with the commentaries.
That works with all struct types(bool, int32) but not with class type (String), could you tell my what I missed so far.

```
namespace Template_String
{
class Program
{    
    public int num1 = 33;
    public static string PLCstrvar = "PLCvarName";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((Int32)Readwrite.READ(PLCstrvar));//working with cast
        Console.WriteLine(Readwrite.READImp2<Int32>(PLCstrvar));//Working with generics
        Console.WriteLine(Readwrite.READImp2<String>(PLCstrvar));//not working
    }
}
public static class Readwrite
{
    //the actual code 
    public static object READ(String PLCVariableName, Boolean WorkingDATA = false)
    {//my code return an type object which is not really good regarding box / unbox implementation
        //I'd like to do something like
        String returnstr = FINDSYMBOL(PLCVariableName, WorkingDATA);
        if (returnstr != "")
        {
            return _plcClient.ReadSymbol(returnstr);
        }
        return "";
    }
    //the projected code
    public static T READImp2<T>(String PLCVariableName, Boolean WorkingDATA = false) where T : new()
    {//The new code uses generics but that doesn't work with String as they are Class and not struct as Boolean are
        //I'd like to do something like
        dynamic returnstr = new T();//resolved in runtime
        returnstr = FINDSYMBOL(PLCVariableName, WorkingDATA);
        if (returnstr != "")
        {
            return(T)_plcClient.ReadSymbol(PLCVariableName);
        }
        return (T)false;//not good
    }

    public static String FINDSYMBOL(String strvalueToreach, Boolean WorkingDATA = false)
    {
        String StrValueToReach = "";
        if (!WorkingDATA)
        {
            for (int inc = 2; inc < 10; inc++)
            {
                StrValueToReach = strvalueToreach;
                if (_plcClient.SymbolExists(StrValueToReach))
                {
                    return StrValueToReach;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "null";
                }
            }
        }
        return "null";
    }
}
```

/*EDIT That is a black box developped by XY developpers far away from me. This code is only used to make the code running without their code !!*/

```
public static class _plcClient  //PLC dynamic link !!dummy code implemented elsewhere!!
    {
    /* this code return if the symbole exist and its value in Int32, Int16, String, Boolean.... type.*/
        private static string nullable="";
        public static bool SymbolExists(string value) { return true;}
        public static object ReadSymbol(String value) { return nullable = "toto"; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: In `READImp2` you are constraining `T` to `new()` and `string` does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: `dynamic` is the same as writing `object`, so you already have a boxing. ` = new T()` is useless, because in the next line you reassign the value of `returnstr`.

Comment: In the end if you want to avoid boxing, you need a "complete" path that doesn't use `object`, so even `_plcClient.ReadSymbol` must have overloads, one for each type, and not simply return `object`.

Comment: InBetween: What does that meanexactely parameter less constructor for string? I understand that the class string with no parameter in the constructor but what does it imply??

Comment: xanatos: One variable is typed as object by the compiler and all instance members will be verified as valid by the compiler. The other variable is typed as dynamic and all instance members will be ignored by the compiler and called by the DLR at execution time.(Andrew Hare) . So I don't think it's the same.

Comment: reading your comment there is no problem of casting those variables, we don't lose any speed at running time is that true?